# Ordenar alfabéticamente una lista con PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Quisiera su ayuda por favor.
Soy principiante y no sé como realizar lo siguiente: Tengo un sistema de cotizaciones el cual imprime en pantalla una tabla con los diferentes campos de un sistema de cotización.
Necesito que los campos que se van agregando se vayan ordenando alfabeticamente.
Es posible realizar esto?
Paso el código:

```html
                        <tbody>
                        <?php
                        $costoTotal = 0;
                        $tiempoTotal = 0;
                        foreach ($servicios as $servicio) {
                            $costoTotal += $servicio->costo;
                            $tiempoTotal += $servicio->tiempoEnMinutos * $servicio->multiplicador;
                            ?>
                            <tr>
                                <td><?php echo htmlentities($servicio->servicio) ?></td>
                                <td>{{<?php echo htmlentities($servicio->costo) ?> | dinero}}</td>
                                <td>{{<?php echo htmlentities($servicio->tiempoEnMinutos * $servicio->multiplicador) ?>
                                    |
                                    minutosATiempo}}
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        <?php } ?>
                        </tbody>
```

Comment: Y de donde vienen los datos? y porque no vienen ordenados ya?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes utilizar el metodo `sort()` para ordenar alfabeticamente.

```
sort($servicio);
foreach ($servicios as $servicio) {
```

//tu codigo

Comment: Bienvenido a SOes, te invito a realizar el [tour] para que conozcas mejor el funcionamiento del sitio. Puedes revisar [¿Cómo escribo una buena respuesta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: Sí, ya probé pero no me ordena, el listado se va generando a medida que se crean las entradas. Y el orden en que muestra es el orden de ingreso. Yo quisiera que se vayan ordenando solas alfabeticamente.